# xlsxwriter conditional format

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

My question is pretty straight, Can I pass multiple types values pair while doing conditional formatting like:

```
worksheet.conditional_format(first row, first col, last row, last col, 
                             {"type": ["no_blanks", "blanks"], 
                              "format": abc})
```

**while doing this I'm getting the below error:**
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Why don’t you just try it?

Comment: @barny i tried and getting error

Comment: Right so that is fairly import aspect of your question. Edit the details of the error into your question, because unless you do, no-one knows what the error is except you.

Comment: @barny edited with error, its type error unhashable type: list

Comment: If the documentation for xlswriter says this is possible, why not report it as a bug on their issue tracker. Is this even possible in Excel? Look at the xlswriter source code. There, three courses of action: take your pick.

Comment: If you turn the list `["no_blanks", "blanks"]` into a tuple,  `("no_blanks", "blanks")` then your unhashable type error will go away. Whether the `conditional_format()` function will understand the tuple is a separate issue, but you might at least then get an informative error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Xlsxwriter documentation on the type parameter for the `worksheet.conditional_format()` ([Link Here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#type)), you'll see in the documentation that there are no allowable parameters for `type: 'blank'` or `type: 'no_blank'`.  So in order for you to make this work you'd have to do separate conditional formats.

Presumably you would like a different format for those cells that are blank versus those that are not blank.  I've provided a reproducible example below that does this.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

first_row=1
last_row=6
first_col=0
last_col=1

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['not blank', '', '', 'not blank', '', '']})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
abc = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
efg = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.conditional_format(first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col,
                             {'type': 'blanks',
                             'format': abc})
worksheet.conditional_format(first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col,
                             {'type': 'no_blanks',
                             'format':    efg})
writer.save()
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output of test.xlsx]

Comment: that's just explain . It was preasumed.