# Xlsxwriter conditional formatting problem

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I have this conditional format shown below:

```
worksheet_budget.conditional_format('D2:D100', {'type': 'cell',
                                            'criteria': 'between',
                                            'minimum': 0,
                                            'maximum': 100,
                                            'format': caution})

worksheet_budget.conditional_format('D2:D100', {'type': 'cell',
                                           'criteria': '<',
                                           'value': 0,
                                           'format': over})
```

It's intent is for every value less than 0, switch the formatting to over and between 0 - 100, to the caution format. However, what ends up happening is that for fields with no value, it will treat it as if it was 0 and use the caution format. I want only fields that have an accounting number attributed to it to have one of the two formats. If it is empty it should have no formatting.

Comment: From the accepted answer to the question [xlsxwriter conditional format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334585/xlsxwriter-conditional-format), is appears you could add a conditional format for `{'type': 'blanks', ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @martineau pointed out, and as highlighted in [the documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html), changing `'type': 'cell'` in your second format to `'type': 'blanks'` should apply the `over` format to all cells where there is no value.

You'll need to remove the `criteria` and `value` keys as well:

```
worksheet_budget.conditional_format('D2:D100', {'type': 'blanks',
                                       'format': over})
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost every time I answer a question about conditional formats in XlsxWriter I say the same thing: first figure out how to do it in Excel and then apply it to XlsxWriter.

It seems like the issue of conditional formats treating blank cells as zero is a know issue/feature in Excel. I followed the advice of one of the methods in [this post](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2499-excel-conditional-formatting-ignore-blank-zero.html) on the issue and set an additional default format for blank cells. I also needed to set the `stop_if_true` property. Here is a working example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

# Add a format. Green fill with dark green text.
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                               'font_color': '#006100'})

# Add a default format.
format3 = workbook.add_format()


# Some sample data to run the conditional formatting against.
data = [
    [34, -75, None, 75, 66, 84, 86],
    [6, 24, 1, 60, 3, 26, 59],
    [None, 79, 97, -13, 22, 5, 14],
    [-27, -71, None, 17, 18, 0, 47],
    [88, 25, -33, 23, 67, "", 36],
    ['', 100, 20, 88, 54, 54, 88],
    [6, 57, '', 28, 10, 41, 48],
    [52, 78, -1, 96, 26, 0, ""],
    [60, -54, 81, None, 81, 90, 55],
    [70, 5, 46, 14, 71, 41, 21],
]


for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write_row(row + 2, 1, row_data)

worksheet.conditional_format('B3:H12', {'type': 'blanks',
                                        'stop_if_true': True,
                                        'format': format3})

worksheet.conditional_format('B3:H12', {'type': 'cell',
                                        'criteria': 'between',
                                        'minimum': 0,
                                        'maximum': 100,
                                        'format': format1})

worksheet.conditional_format('B3:H12', {'type': 'cell',
                                        'criteria': '<',
                                        'value': 0,
                                        'format': format2})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Worth noting the `stop_if_true` *only* needs to be set if you're planning to apply additional formats on the same cells after applying the desired blank format.

Comment: Correct. And that is the case here.